# Keyboard shortcut for Thunar custom actions?

Tags: shortcut-keys, thunar

Is it possible to add keyboard shortcuts to thunars custom actions?
I tried setting the key with mouse-over (the needed option is set in xfce settings) but that do not work for me.

Answer (score 32):

Yes this is possible.

This is an example for the standard custom action "Open Terminal Here":

Open the file `/home/username/.config/Thunar/accels.scm`

than you have to search for:

```
;  (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1398672656481710-1" "")
```

**uca** stands for an custom action and the **1** at the end stands for the first action.

Change this line as follows ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> is only an example you can chose what you want ):

```
  (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1398672656481710-1" "<Alt>t")
```

[image]

be sure you have removed the **";"** at the beginning, to uncomment the line!

To activate the shortcut logout:

```
xfce4-session-logout --logout
```

and log in again.

Open Thunar, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> this should be open the "Open Terminal Here" action.

**Edit 1:** The pagination of the custom action are not always in a logical order. To find the right ID (unique-id) you can look into the `/home/username/.config/Thunar/uca.xml` file:

[image]

**Edit 2:**
Sometimes the shortcuts stops working for me, for example if an confirmation box from Thunar pops up. The consequence is that the focus from the Thunar window are lost. In order to get it back to work you have to make a right click in the Thunar window.

**Edit 3:**
(This is a hint from a anonymous user, not tested)

To avoid the problems explained under Edit 2, you have to modify the `/home/username/.config/Thunar/uca.xml` file.
First you have to change the Line: **sh -c "cd %f; x-terminal-emulator"**
making the lowercase **f** to an uppercase **F**.

Second you have to add following lines:

```
    <audio-files/>
    <image-files/>
    <other-files/>
    <text-files/>
    <video-files/>
```

this is what the code lookes like after the change:

```
<action>
    <icon>utilities-terminal</icon>
    <name>Open terminal here</name>
    <unique-id>1557579822897820-1</unique-id>
    <command>sh -c &quot;cd %F; x-terminal-emulator&quot;</command>
    <description></description>
    <patterns>*</patterns>
    <directories/>
    <audio-files/>
    <image-files/>
    <other-files/>
    <text-files/>
    <video-files/>
</action>
```

Restart Thunar and you're done.

Comment: FWIW, closing all Thunar instances (`killall Thunar`) and opening a new window enabled a new shortcut for me. I'm running i3, not XFCE.